# Access a property in BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails

How to access any property in `BuildConfig.groovy` in `Grails 2.5.1` as accessing configurations in `Config` using

```
grailsApplication.config.theNeededProperty
```

Answer (score 0):

To access properties from `BuildConfig.groovy` in a Gant script you use `grailsSettings.config`:

```
grailsSettings.config.theNeededProperty
```

`BuildConfig.groovy` is for settings related to running Grails commands like `compile` or `run-app`. `Config.groovy` is for all of the runtime settings. It sounds like you should move your property to `Config.groovy`. `BuildConfig.groovy` isn't packaged in the war, so if you want to access something from it while running, you'll need to manually add `BuildConfig.groovy` into the war and use `ConfigSlurper`.

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('path/to/BuildConfig.groovy').toURL())
def value = config.theNeededProperty
```

Comment: i want to access it in a filter

Comment: "i want to access it in a filter" - Your original question makes no mention of that.  You can have your filter implement `GrailsConfigurationAware` and the config object will be injected.  The video at https://objectcomputing.com/products/grails/grails-quickcast-5-reading-config-values/ is on Grails 3, but some of those ideas will be the same in Grails 2.